# Getting all words before a specific word in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset  which has text column as below:

" word1 word2 documented word .... word n"

I have two issues with:

1. While performing text cleaning, I want to remove numbers from this word, but using compress function is compressing everything into 1 word and thus making sentence unreadable?
2. I want to extract all the words before word "documented"

Any please?

input dataset:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCP4Y.png)

Output dataset

[ID Comments                                                    Results
1  increase documented this credit package requires approval   increase
2  new business modification documented ls&f cancelled         new business modification
3  annual renewal documented this package requires approval    annual renewal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61kDc.png)

Comment: If COMPRESS() is removing spaces it is because that is what you told it to do.  Show the code you used. How do you want to output the words before "documented"?  Show what output you want from that example input.

Comment: Hi Tom, my column has values like " a new business documented with id-123456". I want to create a column A which has values "a new business". For compress I am using code comments=compress(comments," ",'d'), but as you mentioned, it is removing all spaces. The output that I am looking for is "a new business documented with id-". Pardon my question structure, I am new to this world :)

Comment: Show an example input dataset.  And then show the resulting dataset you want to create.

Comment: Hi Tom, I have added the sample dataset. Please ignore compress issue for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Learner_new welcome to the party.  When asked to post data don't post pictures.  We want TEXT so we can cut and paste into SAS and run.

Comment: Yeah apologies! cannot do that as data is within organization and I cannot post it since both Stack overflow and personal email is restricted there. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything before a word "documented" the search(FIND) and substring.
You will have to decide how to handle the string when word is not found.

```
data _null_;
   input str $char80.;
   length new $80;
   new = substrn(str,1,find(str,'documented')-1);
   put 'NOTE: ' str=;
   put 'NOTE- ' new=; 
   cards;
a new business documented with id-123456
oldnew business with id-123456
;;;;
   run;

NOTE: str=a new business documented with id-123456
      new=a new business
NOTE: str=oldnew business with id-123456
      new=
```